# How to replace <reference path/> directive with ESM import?

Tags: typescript, import, es6-modules

I'm trying to write a TypeScript application and came to a conclusion that I don't like the `<reference path />` triple-slash directive. I find it more suitable to use `import 'something'` instead.

But when I try to replace my reference paths I keep getting an error that module is unknown.

Here's my folder structure:

```
/app
    /ViewModels
        ApplicationViewModel.ts
    app.ts
```

ApplicationViewModel.ts

```
module ApplicationVM {
    export class ApplicationViewModel {
        constructor(public test:string) {
        }
    }
}
```

app.ts

```
/// <reference path="ViewModels/ApplicationViewModel.ts" />

var a = new ApplicationVM.ApplicationViewModel('test');
```

this one works just fine. How do I get following code to work as well?

```
import * as App from 'noidea';
var a = new App.ApplicationViewModel('test');
```

For 'noidea' I tried: `ViewModels/ApplicationViewModel`, `ApplicationVM` asl. I even combined it with `<reference path />` but it didn't help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove module declaration from ApplicationViewModel.ts (each file is already a module if you use external modules):

```
export class ApplicationViewModel {
    constructor(public test:string) {
    }
}
```

Then in your app.ts

```
import * as App from './ViewModels/ApplicationViewModel';
var a = new App.ApplicationViewModel('test');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Missed that dot in the path and feel awkward.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that you do not need 'module' and 'export =' usage either.

Comment: Yeah, since you code made it work i tried some stuff already =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use so called [external modules](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-going-external):

ApplicationViewModel.ts

```
module ApplicationVM {
    export class ApplicationViewModel {
        constructor(public test:string) {
        }
    }
}

export = ApplicationVM;
```

app.ts

```
import { ApplicationViewModel } from "./ViewModels/ApplicationViewModel"
var a = new ApplicationViewModel('test');
```