# How to solve the "module has no exported member" error?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I am following instructions from [the this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35894727/1033686), but cannot make the solution work.

**Overview**

I want to use `import { Type } from "Module"` instead of `/// <reference path="..." />`

**Structure**

```
-app\
  -ViewModel.ts
  -Program.ts
```

**ViewModel.ts**

```
export module Demo {
    export class ViewModel {
        constructor(public test: string) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.ts**

```
import { ViewModel } from "ViewModel";
```

> Module 'C:/DemoApp/app/ViewModel'
> has no exported member 'ViewModel'.

and...

> Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile.

**Goal**

I want to be able to reference dependencies so that they compile to a single file in order.

---

If I add `"module": "system"` I still get the 1st of the aforementioned errors.

As per the 1st solution, I do not want to lose namespaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Remove the line below from your statement

```
export module Demo
```

and use it like

```
export class ViewModel {
    constructor(public test: string) {
    }
}
```

**Edit:** For namespace, just do something like

```
namespace Demo {
  export class ViewModel {
        constructor(public test: string) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if it works now. Read more about it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

Comment: When I do this I get the error File 'pathtofile' is not a module

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be typo.

```
export const Demo = () => {} cannot be exported if it does not return a value.

export const Demo =()=> () can be exported without return.
```

Answer (score -2):

May not be or check the module which you're using there.

```
export a () => {
   console.log("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32335431)